# Data Transfer Formula for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have three pieces of information:

1. Start Date & Time (MM/DD/YY HH:MM AM/PM)
2. End Date & Time (MM/DD/YY HH:MM AM/PM)
3. Total Amount of Data transferred, in bytes.

Excel is able to calculate the difference between #1 and #2 with a simple cell math (B2-A2).

What is the formula to find the average bitrate?

Bonus points for conversion formulas for KBps and MBps. :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Divide 3. by (2. - 1.). This will get you the number of bytes transfered per day.

To convert B/day to B/s divide that value by 86400 (60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours)

To convert B/s to KB/s divide that value for 1024 (2^10). This reasoning is valid for larger multiples, such that B/s to MB/s is just dividing by 2^20.